# Erlang Use in Payment Systems‏

Tags: erlang

I am trying to implement payment messaging middleware and would like to explore the option of using Erlang/OTP.
The application will be used in banking industry to interface with EFT payment networks and core banking system to process card transactions.

It will be responsible to perform following tasks:

1. Communicate with external networks (like VISA and MasterCard) using
   ISO 8583 message format.
2. Receive huge amount of data over the socket (HEX,BINARY,EBCIDIC)
   which represent financial transactions.
3. Parse/decode the received data.
4. Perform some checking in database for validation
5. Interface with host security module to validate customer PIN and
   other security checks.
6. Sends the request to core banking system via XML or web services
   call
7. Respond back to external interfaces by formulating the response
   message in ISO 8583 format

Obviously, such applications have to be concurrent and fast enough to process transactions within few seconds.
Now my question here, is Erlang a good choice for implementing this type of applications ? Can Erlang handle string processing efficiently without impacting the system performance?

As stated before, there will be a lot of string manipulation to decode data received over the network, so I am not sure whether erlang fits perfectly or not.

Comment: Is persistence needed in some way for your application?

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever heard about [Klarna](https://www.klarna.com/us/about-us)? They are using Erlang exactly for this purposes. They are pretty [active](http://engineering.klarna.com/tag/erlang/) in Erlang community. You can also check out their [GitHub repositories](https://github.com/klarna).

1. Erlang is a perfect tool for implementing protocols and communicating with external resources.
2. Erlang is a perfect tool for implementing protocols and communicating with external resources.
3. Did I mention that Erlang is a perfect tool for implementing protocols?
4. It's not a problem for Erlang, even some high performance and high scalable databases are implemented in Erlang.
5. Erlang has some capability to implement security measures. For example, you can set `sensitive` flag which disables every debug and trace information for the process so it no longer reveals its state including message queue. For higher standards you always can use code written in C and using OS level protection. Did I mention that Erlang is a perfect tool for communicating with external resources?
6. XML is supported in Erlang as well.
7. Did I mention that Erlang is a perfect tool for implementing protocols?

More questions:

- Concurrent and fast enough - check.
- Good choice for implementing this type of applications - ask Klarna.
- Handle string processing efficiently without impacting the system performance - I don't know better system for handling strings than `iolist` with binaries - check

Answer (score 2):

Your question somehow implies that processing ISO 8583 means processing text. Erlang represents text in [two different ways](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real):

1. [List](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html) - is a linked list of individual chars. Takes more space (each element is the char and an address to the next element) and is slow at processing long texts but is very easy to work with since [lists are the basic types](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html) in functional languages.
2. [Binary](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html) - is a set of bytes [stored in memory](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html), similar to arrays in C/C++, but with much better [support for processing and pattern matching](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html).

Both types [support Unicode](http://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html) ([including UTF-8](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html)) very well.

Erlang doesn't excel at raw text processing (Perl is arguably better) but Erlang excels at efficiently implementing and handling various protocols, including text protocols. It was invented by Ericsson to [handle data in telecommunication](http://ftp.nsysu.edu.tw/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/erlang/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf) systems, which is full of protocols. The core Erlang library, [OTP](http://erlang.org/doc/man_index.html), contains a huge amount of modules that implement handlers for the most popular protocols: [ASN.1](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/asn1/asn1_getting_started.html), [Base64](http://erlang.org/doc/man/base64.html), [Corba](http://erlang.org/doc/man/corba.html), [LDAP](http://erlang.org/doc/man/eldap.html), HTTP, [SNMP](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/snmp/), TCP, UDP, SCTP among others.

Some of the most popular messaging systems, which process text messages for obvious reasons, are written in Erlang: [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [EMQTT](http://emqtt.io/), [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/).

There is also a [library to process ISO 8583](https://code.google.com/archive/p/erl8583/) with forks on Gihub: [1st fork](https://github.com/b00ris/erl8583), [2nd fork](https://github.com/mgwidmann/erl8583).

But probably the most important reason for choosing Erlang is not its support for protocol implementations but its ability to scale. Erlang implements its [own processes](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html), which are different than system processes. Erlang can create millions of processes on a modest CPU to handle millions of jobs concurrently. See how it's used at [Wooga](http://blog.wooga.com/post/133339012278/tech-at-wooga-elli) and [WhatsApp](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/2/26/the-whatsapp-architecture-facebook-bought-for-19-billion.html) among others.